# Adding a Marker to jVectorMap

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, vector, jvectormap

SO,

I've managed to get a custom map to display using the jVectorMap plugin and I'm trying to add custom markers, but when I follow the example here: http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/ nothing happens. Am I just missing something simple in the code?

Here's my code before adding a marker:

```
 //@code_start
      $(function(){
        $('#usmxmap').vectorMap({
          map: 'map',
          regionsSelectable: false,
          markersSelectableOne: true,
          backgroundColor: '#cfdbdd',
          regionStyle: {
            initial: {
      fill: '#5e7073',
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      stroke: 'none',
      "stroke-width": 0,
      "stroke-opacity": 1
      },
      hover: {
      fill: 'black'
      },
      selected: {
      fill: 'yellow'
      },
      selectedHover: {
      }
      },
        });
      });
      //@code_end
```

The JsFiddle that produces: 
http://jsfiddle.net/73aze/5/

And here's what I've got to add a marker:

```
//@code_start
      $(function(){
        $('#usmxmap').vectorMap({
          map: 'map',
          regionsSelectable: false,
          markersSelectableOne: true,
          backgroundColor: '#cfdbdd',
          markers: [{
          coords: [60, 110],
          name: 'Escalator 1',
          style: {fill: 'yellow'}
          }],
          regionStyle: {
            initial: {
      fill: '#5e7073',
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      stroke: 'none',
      "stroke-width": 0,
      "stroke-opacity": 1
      },
      hover: {
      fill: 'black'
      },
      selected: {
      fill: 'yellow'
      },
      selectedHover: {
      }
      },
        });
      });
      //@code_end
```

As you can see from the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Z9u4T/3/), that just causes the map to disappear and I can't determine what I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Marca

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'centralMeridian' of undefined` - does that mean anything to you? I've not used this plugin before, but the console is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

`}, }); }); //@code_end`

must be

`} }); }); //@code_end`

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a mess in your `jsfiddles`.
Try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/154/).

And this is your [modified second jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9u4T/20/). Importing raw from github apparently was the issue. I linked to `jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js` on jvectormap's web page instead and now it works.